# How to make a search-engine using tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, error-handling, search-engine

I tried on making a gui-based search engine in python, but for some reason I am facing two errors.

1. I am unable to locate the 'Search' button even though I have added it in code.
2. (I think so) Due to not being able to use the search button I am unable to find any search results even after pressing enter.

###Edit

After the help from all of you ,I have made changes to the code but still it is no good.the new code is here :

```
import requests,webbrowser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tkinter import  *

structure=Tk()
structure.geometry("1280*1280")
structure.title("Cgo Engine")
label=Label(structure,text="Cgo Engine",bg="dark grey",fg="Gold",font=("ComicSans",60,"italic"))
label.pack(side=TOP)
structure.config(background="dark grey")
text=StringVar()
###
def searches():
     data=requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q='+text.get())
     soup=BeautifulSoup(data.content,"html.parser")
     result=soup.select(".kCrYT a")
     for ans in result[:6]:
        search=ans.get("href")
        search=search[7:]
        search=search.split("&")
        webbrowser.open(search[0])
        
###
label=Label(structure,font=("Times",15,"bold"),text="Enter here to search",bg="black",fg="yellow")
label.place(x=600,y=350)
enter=Entry(structure,font=("Times",15,"bold"),textvar=text,width=60,bd=2,bg="white")
enter.place(x=600,y=500)
button=Button(structure,text="Search",font=("Times",15,"bold"),width=10,bd=2,bg="white",command=search)
button.place(x=100,y=200)
structure.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can see the "Search" button (although it overlaps the entry widget) when running your code after changing `structure.geometry("1230*1230")` to `structure.geometry("1230x1230")` and `command=search` to `command=searches`.

Comment: Your function names are mismatching, in function definition it is ```SEARCHES()``` but in call it is ```SEARCH()```

Comment: I fixed errors in your code then run it and gui has search button. I typed sth random and searched. It opened new tabs in my browser like 4 or 5. So your problem is not with your search button.

Comment: Your updated code still has the issues mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: yes I know that ,I have just left it as it is so that others can see what I was doing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

this two things must be canged to run your code ok:

> structure.geometry("1230*1230")

will become: 'structure.geometry("1230**x**1230")'

> button=Button(structure,text="Search",font=("Times",15,"bold"),width=30,bd=2,bg="white",command=search)

will become: 'button=Button(structure,text="Search",font=("Times",15,"bold"),width=30,bd=2,bg="white",command=search**es**)'

then your code will run ok.

Comment: After changing all the positions of x and y differently and following your advises ,I was able to run the code.Thanks a lot !